# Checking string equivalency

Tags: r, string

I am stuck when trying to check equivalency of elements in a vector of strings

```
> head(vector_of_strings)
[1] "    " "SC  " " 2.6" "WT  " " 1.0" "WT  "
> is.character(vector_of_strings)
[1] TRUE
> "SC  " %in% vector_of_strings
[1] FALSE
> "WT  " %in% vector_of_strings
[1] FALSE
```

The vector seems to have elements that are equivalent, but reports otherwise. Should I modify the data type or check for equivalency in another way?

Comment: Can you give `dput(vector_of_strings)`?

Comment: `> dput(vector_of_strings)
c("    ", "SC  ", " 2.6", "WT  ", " 1.0", "WT  ", "    ", "SC  ", 
" 0.6", "WT  ", "    ", " 1 @", "    ", " 1 @", "    ", "    ", 
"    ", "    ", "    ", "    ", " 3 @", "    ", " 3 @", "    ", 
"    ", "SC  ", "    ", " 0.2", "WT  ", " 0.4", "WT  ", "    ", 
" 0.0", "WT  ", "    ", "    ", "    ", "    ", "    ", "    ", 
"    ", "SC  ", "    ", "    ", "    ", "    ", "    ", "0")` @Axeman

Comment: a typo: you have an additional "space" in your check of "SC  " and "WT  "

Comment: the dput comment is not showing on stackoverflow correct. There was a copy/paste error. It exists with two spaces even with dput. Additionally I tried `> "SC " %in% vector_of_strings` with a single space as @KoenV mentioned and it doesn't work.

Comment: Use `trimws` to remove leading and trailing whitespaces to avoid such issues, try `"SC" %in% trimws(vector_of_strings)`

Comment: Hi @RonakShah. Thank you for the feedback. However, it doesn't seem to work. `"SC" %in% trimws(vector_of_strings) [1] FALSE`

Comment: works for me from the `dput` which you shared. `vector_of_strings <- dput(vector_of_strings) c(" ", "SC ", " 2.6", "WT ", " 1.0", "WT ", " ", "SC ", " 0.6", "WT ", " ", " 1 @", " ", " 1 @", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " 3 @", " ", " 3 @", " ", " ", "SC ", " ", " 0.2", "WT ", " 0.4", "WT ", " ", " 0.0", "WT ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", "SC ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", "0"); "SC" %in% trimws(vector_of_strings)
[1] TRUE`

Comment: For whatever reason, the vector is not modified on my screen after trying trimws. See code here `> head(trimws(vector_of_strings))
[1] "    " "SC  " " 2.6" "WT  " " 1.0" "WT  "`

Comment: There may exist some unicode "invisible" characters that `trimws` is not able to remove (because they're not whitespace). You may want to have a look at `?Encoding`, `stringi::stri_unescape_unicode` and `stringi::stri_escape_unicode`

Comment: Thanks @PavoDive. I think you're correct. This is data scraped from a webpage and Encoding reveals the strings are in UTF-8 format. I will explore how to deal with this format. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: use `stringi::stri_unescape_unicode` to check the character numbers (they should come like `\U03B1` or `<U+03B1>` and then `gsub` the whole vector to get rid of them. Have a look to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36108790/trouble-with-strings-with-u0092-unicode-characters

Comment: you can use `repair_encoding` too: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37867465/r-rvest-encoding-errors-with-utf-8